# How do I calculate the Probability of these 3 Events Occurring

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I wanted some help in clarifying how to go about a question that I have.

Basically I have 3 probabilities; $P(Female)$, $P(Age)$ and $P(Flight)$ that is the probability that someone is a female, that they are a certain age and that they are going to fly a certain flight.

How would I go about finding out the probability that someone is a female, of a certain age and that she is going to fly a certain flight.

I'm thinking $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ but I am not sure on how to calculate this. Thank you.

Comment: Unclear what data available to you.  Denoting $(AB)$ as the event where both $A$ and $B$ occur, one approach is $p(B) \times p(A|B) \times p(C|[AB]).$

Comment: How can I make the question more clear? Apologies

Comment: The punchline is that given an event $A$ and an event $B$, the probability both events occur is indeed written as $\Pr(A\cap B)$.  Now... for *independent* events, you can expand $\Pr(A\cap B)$ as $\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$... however this is true if and *only if* the events are independent.  It is not a safe assumption that these are in fact independent.  For instance, a flight to Cancun during spring break may be more likely to contain younger college students going to party on spring break than a flight to Billings which likely contains older passengers...

Comment: So... if you wish to make assumptions (*which are most likely invalid assumptions to make*) in order to simplify matters... then sure, just multiply your three probabilities together... however the most correct answer is that you won't be able to calculate what you want with the information you are given, and that to calculate what you want you essentially need to have been given the information you want ahead of time... with far more information about how these events interact with one another.

Comment: You can also consider all females of the certain age range on the particular flight, divided by all possible male and female passengers of all ages on all flights.  So, as @JMoravitz says, it depends on how your data is presented.